# how to change example.com to www.example.com in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I have tried lots of option to change my url. But I am not able to do so I have change the settings in wordpress general settings but it is not change the url from

example.com to www.example.com

I also added the these lines in wp-config

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.example.com/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.example.com/');
```

But this also not working. Please anybody guide me regarding this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please ;

.htacces entry to redirect anything.example.com (and example.com itself) to www.example.com:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need www version of website to be automatically redirected to non-www version than you should put this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

if you want to redirect non-www version to www version than this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: it might be interfering with other rewrite rules you have in your htaccess

Comment: this is the full htaccess file code of my website

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase //
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . //index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress